# Windows 8 style listview for web

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8

I want to be able to display items in a sought of grid like in a Windows 8 Listview. The items will be squares (tiles).

I can get them to display like this by creating div's that sit on the same line.

Item 1 Item 2 Item 3

Item 4 Item 5 Item 6

But I would like them to display like this

Item 1 Item 3 Item 5

Item 2 Item 4 Item 6

I wonder if anyone knows how to achieve this.

Comment: How are the two any different?

Comment: I think he figured it out

Comment: Sorry I forgot to change it.

Comment: easiest way would be to have a floating container that will have item 1, item 2, then another floating container with 3 and 4, and so on. syntax wise, the items won't technically be together, but it should give the effect you want.

Comment: The problem is that the content is dynamically generated and the number of items is variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a demo here [JsBIN](http://jsbin.com/akakad/2/edit)

With this demo, we set the `width` and `height` of each `li` item in javascript and the `height` or `max-height` of the list in CSS.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It has worked for me. I chose it over 
Jeremy Foster's because I think it will provide wider compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

The IE10 engine is the same engine that Windows 8 uses, but the ListView control that is used in Windows 8 apps is a custom control that is not available outside the WinJS framework. The engine does implement the [CSS flexbox standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) and details it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453474.aspx). The cross browser support for the flexbox is pretty good (see [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)).
A flexbox includes the ability to arrange elements vertically and wrap. The combination of those two things would implement what you're looking for. Something like this (I'll spare you all the vendor prefixes and just use the -ms version):

```
<!-- HTML snippet -->
<div class="parent">
  <div>item 1</div>
  <div>item 2</div>
  <div>item 3</div>
  <div>item 4</div>
  <div>item 5</div>
  <div>item 6</div>
</div>

/* CSS snippet */
.parent {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  height: 300px; /* adjust to create the two rows you're looking for */
}

.parent > div {
  /* you may want to set some flex properties on the children here */
}
```